# Deep Link doesn't open the app instead does a google search

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, deep-linking

I have been using Expo to develop a react-native app, The functionality I am currently trying to implement is to share a link with friends on platforms such as fb messenger/whatapp or even normal texts and when they click this link it will launch my app to a specific page using the parameters.

After extensive research online - I’ve come to a blocker, following expo’s documentation I defined a scheme for my app - when I press share everything works correctly a message is created and I’m able to share content but only as string.

I am using react-natives Share library to share to an app and I’m using Expo to provide me with the link.

Ideally my first goal is to get the app opening using the Expo Link before I explore further into adding more functionality to the link.

```
Share.share({
    message: "Click Here to View More! " + Linking.makeUrl( ' ' , { postkey : "7a5d6w2x9d6s3a28d8d});
    url: Linking.makeUrl( ' ' , { pkey : gkey });
    title: 'This post is amazing',
  })
  .then((result) =>{
    console.log(result)
      if(result === 'dismissedAction'){
        return
      }
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

In the root of my app I have also defined the event handlers: App.js

```
_handleRedirect=(event)=> {
         let {path,queryParams} = Linking.parse(event);
        Alert.alert(`queryparams : ${event}  path : ${path} `) 

         this.props.navigation.navigate("Post_Detail",{key:queryParams.postkey}) 
         
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  let scheme = 'nxet'
 Linking.getInitialURL()
    .then(url => {
      console.log("App.js getInitialURL Triggered")
      // this.handleOpenURL({ url });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
  Linking.addEventListener('url', ({url}) =>  this._handleRedirect(url));;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}
```

When I share the link to Whatsapp, Facebook Messenger or even just messages or notes it appears as myapplink://, I try to enter this into the browser and instead of asking me to open my app - it does a google search.

Please note I am attempting to have this working on Android Device and facing this issue

Is there something I am doing incorrectly?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can not open external links, means other than http, https on Android. But you can on iOS. In order to be able to open your expo links, you need proper anchor tags on android. You can create html mails and give it a try, you will see it is gonna work on Android as well.